# Spark Cassandra Multiple Partition RDD

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, datastax

I have cassandra event table like :

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT (
    eventType ascii,
    day ascii,
    ......
    PRIMARY KEY ((eventType, day), ...)
);
```

where days like '20150824', '20150825'

I want to create RDD with multiple partitions(multiple `day`). Based on my readings, I had to to custom partitioning(lack of IN support) on Spark 1.2 and doing :

```
JavaRDD<CassandraRow> unionTable = null;
for (String day : days) {
    if (unionTable == null) {
        unionTable = javaFunctions(sparkContext).cassandraTable("event_keyspace", "event")//
                .select("columns_to_select")//
                .where("eventType='" + eventType + "' and day = '" + day + "'");
    } else {
        unionTable = unionTable.union(javaFunctions(sparkContext).cassandraTable("event_keyspace", "event")//
                .select("columns_to_select")//
                .where("eventType='" + eventType + "' and day = '" + day + "'");
    }
}

// do job on union table
```

Now I want to use Spark 1.4 but I got cast exception with the code above. `UnionRDD` cannot be cast to `CassandraTableScanRDD`

I see that IN query is supported with 1.4 but its performance is awful(1 task) when i do :

```
unionTable = javaFunctions(sparkContext).cassandraTable("event_keyspace", "event")//
                .select("columns_to_select")//
                .where("eventType='" + eventType + "' and day IN('" + StringUtils.join(days, "', '") + "')";
```

What is the best practice to achieve this with Java API? What about `joinWithCassandraTable`? I don't want to bring all data to Spark and do filtering. I see some examples but they mostly not applicable with java API.

My code with new Java API looks like:

```
List<PartitionKey> rows = new ArrayList<>();
rows.add(new PartitionKey()); // PartitionKey contains eventType and day 
CassandraJavaPairRDD<PartitionKey, SelectedData> pairRDD = javaFunctions(sparkContext.parallelize(rows))//
        .joinWithCassandraTable("event_keyspace", "event",
            CassandraJavaUtil.someColumns(..SelectedData instance variables..), //
            CassandraJavaUtil.someColumns("eventType", "day"), //
            CassandraJavaUtil.mapRowTo(SelectedData.class), CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(PartitionKey.class));//
```

and I call map function to get only selected data.

Is this the best practice?

Comment: joinWithCassandraTable is most likely what you want to use as long as number of partition keys is pretty large.

Comment: what do you mean with large? a hundred is large? Is my joinWithCassandraTable usage correct and the best practice? Its hard to find code examples.

Comment: Large is 10's of thousands. If your number of requests is close to a small multiple of cores in your system you are basically starting a giant distributed task to retrieve a very small amount of data. If it isn't necessary for future distributed computation I would just do this from a normal driver connection.

Comment: wouldn't i lose data locality? my actual model is a bit diffferent from this one and rows are pretty large. I still tried IN query but I got bad performance.

Comment: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/b1.4/spark-cassandra-connector-java/src/main/java/com/datastax/spark/connector/japi/RDDJavaFunctions.java#L132-L152

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/2_loading.md#repartitioning-rdds-based-on-a-cassandra-tables-replication

Comment: performance decreased.. my rows are pretty wide.. i will check in details. thanks for help

Comment: Again don't go expecting excellent performance on smaller key sets. You'll be better off just using the standard java driver and doing async requests.

Comment: actually hour info(maybe minute) is in partition key. my analysis will be done mostly on monthly basis. 30dayx24hour partition keys and every partition have around lets say 10million records. you say put minute on partition key to get better performance?

Comment: also my application is multi-tenant and number of records in a partition vary too much. i know for some of them i don't even need spark. but for some of them, its a must.

Comment: with joinWithCassandraTable i see only PROCESS_LOCAL taks. if i use repartitionByCassandraReplica before joinWithCassandraTable, i see NODE_LOCAL tasks too. Thats why performance decreased, i think.